# How to add Two Header and Two Footer for Multi-Store

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, header, footer, custom-theme

I have **used the same theme for my multi-store,** I need to change header and footer completely for my second store.

**How can add 2 headers and 2 footers for my multi-store?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)As per magento standard, Create new theme and assign that theme to the new store(which you want to change header and footer).
Now just copy headed.phtml and footer.html and past it in new theme, update those file html or CSS as you want.

2) Add magento store id or code condition for header and footer.

A) using store id:

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == 'yourStoreID'){ ?>

         //Insert your HTML or JS Code Here

    <?php } else { ?>

         //insert your HTML or JS Code Here

    <?php } ?>
```

B) Using store code

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'yourStoreCode'){ ?>

     //HTML or JS Code Here

<?php } else { ?>

     //HTML or JS Code Here

<?php } ?>
```

Hope above solution will work for you.

Comment: yes good solution,, but i need to work the same theme with two stores, and i want to change header and footer for my 2nd store, how can i archive this.

Comment: I mean, header and footer only change, remaining everything same. So how can i change header and footer.

Comment: Yes, you can use 2 option add store ID or code condition for updating header and footer for another store. Please let me know if you want in detail?

Comment: Yes, i need details of changing header and footer

Comment: Please check my updated ANS. Please accept this as answer if it is helpful to you.

Comment: i am newbie, could you pls help me, how can i apply this code in backend.

Comment: shall you join with me https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70797/how-to-add-two-header-and-two-footer-for-multi-store

Comment: Dear you need to apply above code in theme/templates/page/html/header.html and footer.html file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70798/discussion-between-zus-and-nits).